# Determine if some relative directory is part of absolute path using std::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, path, c++17, std-filesystem

I can't figure out how to identify if absolute path contains some relative directory inside it using std::filesystem::path but still with no luck. I have the following peace of code:

```
const std::filesystem::path absolutePath = "/Users/user/Library/Preferences";
const std::filesystem::path relativePath = "Library/Preferences";
bool isSubDir = isSubDirectory(absolutePath, relativePath);
```

isSubDirectory should return true in such case. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) class provides iterators to the first and one past the last element. So you could search for the relative path inside the absolute path using `std::search`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

bool isSubDirectory(const fs::path& absolutePath, const fs::path& relativePath)
{
    auto it = std::search(absolutePath.begin(), absolutePath.end(), relativePath.begin(), relativePath.end());
    return it != absolutePath.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I mean not exist, I need to determine if relative path is part of absolute.

Comment: @Oleg A misunderstanding there. Check my updated answer.